# Need Help on problem with Cdbl Function on different Excel Versions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2016

After exporting data, I have CSV with numbers like `; ,34 ; ,6483` (understand that is `0,34` or `0,6483`). When using Excel 2010, I can cast `CDbl(",34")` and it works fine, but in Excel 2016, it says there is a mismatch Problem. I'm here cause I cant figure out whats the problem.

Already changed decimal separator, doesn't work.

```
Dim arreglo() As String
'... filling the array...
arreglo(R, C) = one_line(C)

CDbl(arreglo(R, C))   '<--------------------
```

OK in Excel 2010
   Mismatch in Excel 2016

Comment: Why are you treating numbers from csv files as text? Are they not recognized as numbers when you open them with Excel?

Comment: Yes. Why not `Dim arreglo() As Double` so you don't have to cast?

Comment: It is part of a bigger code and lthe logic has to do with it. Main problem is difference with Versions Excel. Couldnt find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a difference between Excel 2010 and 2016 but an issue with the decimal separator that is either set in the operating system or in Excel itself. So make sure the decimal separator matches the one used in the CSV.

For example if the CSV uses comma then …

1. Remember the original state of the decimal separator.
2. Change `Application.DecimalSeparator` to the same as used in CSV.
3. Do your stuff.
4. Revert it to the original state (also if an error occurs).

So it would be something like this:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
    'remember original state of decimal separator
    Dim OriginalUseSystemSeparators As Boolean
    OriginalUseSystemSeparators = Application.UseSystemSeparators
    Dim OriginalDecimalSeparator As String
    OriginalDecimalSeparator = Application.DecimalSeparator

    'change it to what you need for your CSV
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False 'necessary otherwise next line is without effect!
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "," 'must match CSV decimal separator

    On Error Goto REVERT_DECIMAL 'in case of error we want to rever the old state
    'your code here
    MsgBox CDbl(",34") 'this should work now!

    'no Exit Sub here!
REVERT_DECIMAL:
    'revert it after 
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = OriginalUseSystemSeparators 
    Application.DecimalSeparator = OriginalDecimalSeparator 
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that using this approach it should not be necessary to convert any numbers. If you import the CSV where I wrote `'your code here` it should automatically recognize the numbers as numbers now because the decimal separator maches the one in the CSV file.